# Event Raised in a class, handle this event in a form no response

Tags: vb.net

I am working with `VS2008` on `Win 7` os. My problem here is in my app is reading scanner data using a `class -- class1`, so once the data is read, I send out code to raise an event from another `class -- class2`. I have multiple forms that could use this scanned data, so, whatever the form on top will handle this even. I can see the event raised, but the handler on the active form doesn't response. Could you please tell me what is the problem in my code?

*class1 read the scanned data and call class2 to raise event*:

```
Public Class class1   
    Private WithEvents evnt As New class2

    Private Sub DataReceived()       
        evnt.ScanData()        
    End Sub
End class   'end class1

Public Class class2
    Public Event NewScanData(ByVal ScanData As String)

    Public Sub ScanData()
        RaiseEvent NewScanData(ScanData)
        'MsgBox("Invoked event")
    End Sub
End Class    'end class2
```

** note: I can see the message Invoked event shows, that means event does get raised. but the form class below seems not receiving the event:

```
Public Class Form1
    Friend WithEvents event1 As New class2
    Private Sub GetScanData(ByVal ScanData As String) Handles event1.NewScanData
         'do something to process scanned data
    End sub
End Class
```

Thanks you

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're processing it in the form1 and not in the class itself as a function? If so you could just keep the events in one class and return the end value. Unless, you're doing something that needs it that way.

Comment: this structure is pretty convoluted.  If Class1 gets the data, why does the event get raised by class2?  You might have `Class2` defined as  an internal helper for Class1 to do something beforehand, then raise the event.

Comment: There are other problems - `ScanData` is never passed to Class2 yet it just appears when needed.  use `Option Strict` always. `whatever the form on top will handle this even[t]`.  No, any and all forms with and active event handler will get the event; you'd have to add code to ignore it in some cases, which begs the question why there is more than one subscriber

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the event1 instance in Form1 is not the same instance on which ScanData is being called. You probably have 2 instances of class2. One has ScanData called on it, and the other is in Form1 completely disconnected from it. Somewhere I think you need to set `Form1.event1 = class1.evnt` or `class1.evnt = Form1.event1`.

Comment: Class1 will work fine, but that's because it's working with the same instance of Class2 that it created. Form1 is creating another copy and nothing is triggering the event on that copy.

Comment: correct - I goofed up some test code and put the event in the wrong place...I could not figure it why it seemed to be working

Answer (score 0):

I modified your Form1 code a bit.  I put a button on it that calls your ScanData method, which results in the event1 firing in Class Form1.  Maybe this will help?

```
Public Class Form1
    Friend WithEvents event1 As New Class2
    Private Sub GetScanData(ByVal ScanData As String) Handles event1.NewScanData
        'do something to process scanned data
        MessageBox.Show(ScanData)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        event1.ScanData()   ' if you call this method event1's NewScanData fires
    End Sub
End Class
```